# Menu Icon mudar de cor ao passar o mouse em cima WPF c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wpf

Olá, 
Estou tentando fazer com que quando passar o mouse trocar a cor.
O Icon do menu deve ficar branco como a letra (header) como mostrado na imagem
abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu codigo do menu e esse

```
 <Menu Style="{DynamicResource StandardClienteMenu}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="50">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItemUsuario" Style="{DynamicResource StandardMenuClienteItem}"  Header="Usuario"  >
                            <MenuItem.Icon >
                                <fa:ImageAwesome Width="14" Height="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Icon="User" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MenuItem}}"/>
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                <MenuItem x:Name="Paramentros" Header="Parâmetros da empresa" Click="MenuParametros_Click" Style="{DynamicResource StandardMenuClienteItem}" >
                                    <MenuItem.Icon >
                                        <fa:ImageAwesome Width="14" Height="14"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Icon="Cogs" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=Paramentros}" />
                                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                                </MenuItem>
                     </MenuItem>
                </Menu>
```

E o Style e esse seguinte:

```
<Style x:Key="StandardMenuClienteItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BlueBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"   />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <!--  Border 1  -->
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"

                        BorderThickness="0"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0"
                                              Width="Auto"
                                              MinWidth="17"
                                              SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                          Margin="7 1 5 1"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          Visibility="Visible"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Icon" 
                                           />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="IGTHost"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          Margin="5 1 5 1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="InputGestureText" />
                        <Grid x:Name="ArrowPanel"
                              Grid.Column="3"
                              Margin="2 0 6 0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Popup x:Name="SubMenuPopup"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               Focusable="false"
                               HorizontalOffset="-1"
                               Cursor="Hand"
                               IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Placement="Right"
                               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                            <Grid Margin="0 0 5 5">
                                <!--  Border 2  -->
                                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder"
                                         Cursor="Hand"
                                        Background="Transparent"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SubMenu"
                                          Margin="2"
                                          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black" />
                                    </Border.Effect>
                                </Border>
                                <!--  Border 3  -->
                                <Border x:Name="TransitionBorder"
                                        Width="0"
                                        Height="2"
                                        Margin="1 0 0 0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource SubmenuclienteItemBackgroundHighlighted}"
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemClienteBackgroundHighlighted}"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                         Cursor="Hand"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 0 6 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenu" Property="Margin" Value="2 3 2 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TransitionBorder" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 0 6 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 3 0 3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 3 0 3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemClienteBackground}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BlueWebBrush}" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="CornerRadius" Value="5,5,5,5" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanelPath" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundSelected}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                             </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MenuDisabledForeground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyleCliente" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BlueWebBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"   />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <!--  Border 1  -->
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col0"
                                              Width="Auto"
                                              MinWidth="17"
                                              SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuTextColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" />
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col3" Width="14" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Icon" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderHost"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="IGTHost"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          Margin="8 1 8 1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          ContentSource="InputGestureText" />
                        <Grid x:Name="ArrowPanel"
                              Grid.Column="3"
                              Margin="4 0 6 0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowPanelPath"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M0,0 L0,8 L4,4 z"
                                  Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Popup x:Name="SubMenuPopup"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               Focusable="false"
                               HorizontalOffset="0"
                               IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               Placement="Right"
                               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}">
                            <Grid Margin="0 0 5 5">
                                <!--  Border 2  -->
                                <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource SubmenuclienteItemBackgroundHighlighted}"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SubMenu"
                                          Margin="2"
                                          Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    <Border.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Color="Black" />
                                    </Border.Effect>
                                </Border>
                                <!--  Border 3  -->
                                <Border x:Name="TransitionBorder"
                                        Width="0"
                                        Height="2"
                                        Margin="1 0 0 0"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource SubmenuclienteItemBackgroundHighlighted}"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                        BorderThickness="0"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="False" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 0 6 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenu" Property="Margin" Value="2 3 2 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="Placement" Value="Bottom" />
                        <Setter TargetName="TransitionBorder" Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Grid}" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6 0 6 2" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col0" Property="MinWidth" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Col3" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="IGTHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 3 0 3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuclienteItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />


                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 3 0 3" />
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanel" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuClienteItemRedlightedBackground}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuClienteItemRedlightedBackground}" />

                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuClienteItemRedlightedBackground}" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="SubmenuItem" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuclienteItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MenuSeparatorBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1 1 1 1" />
                        <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}" />
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="ArrowPanelPath" Property="Fill" Value="{DynamicResource BackgroundSelected}" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="SubMenuPopup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource SubmenuItemBackgroundHighlighted}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os eventos `MouseEnter` e `MouseLeave`.

O `MouseEnter` é executado no momento que você posiciona o cursor sobre o elemento (hover).

O `MouseLeave` é executado no momento em que o cursor sai do elemento.

Exemplo abaixo simulando a troca de fundo em um grid:

```
private void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        grid.Background = Brushes.Gray;
    }

    private void Grid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid grid = sender as Grid;
        grid.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Basta você adaptar para sua necessidade.